# Get regex in python to return the matched pattern (not match object)

Tags: python, regex

So I have a list of emails within other stuff in several string lines. I want my code to return **only** the matched pattern, here is the function:

```
def match_separator(s):
    mail = s.lower()
    mail = re.match(r"[^@]+@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+){1,2}",s)
    print(mail)
```

It looks like it is finding the emails correctly, but the result it returns is useless for my next steps:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='xxx@xx.xx'>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='xx@xx.com'>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='xx@gmail.com'>
```

I can't do anything  with this output. I tried several things taking what I understood from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like `print(mail.group(0))` and similar, but the only thing this gets me is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any  ideas on how to do it? It seems like getting the matched pattern in a regex should be really straightforward (this is what most use cases would be after, right?) Yet here I am.

**EDIT**
OK, thanks guys, I was being obtuse and this is why :

The first line passed to the function didn't have a match so the program was ending with the exception. This change fixed my issue:

```
def match_separator(s):
    mail = s.lower()
    mail = re.match(r"[^@]+@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+){1,2}",s)
    try:
        print(mail.group())
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

This bypasses the first lines which are non matching and returns only what I want.

Comment: If `mail` is a `<regex.Match object ...>` then it will not be `None` simultaneously. It seems what you print and what you try to use the `.group` method on are two different things. Please show the exact code you are using and some example inputs which trigger the error.

Comment: Your `NoneType` error is the result of the pattern not matching.  You had no match object, only `None`, and of course `None.group(...)` doesn't work.  If you *do* have a match, and therefore a match object, then `match.group(0)` will return the text that the regex matched.  You can also get portions of it by grouping parts of the regex in parehtheses, and using indices 1, 2, ... instead of 0 when calling `group()`.

Comment: Or did you try to use `.group` on the return value of `match_separator`, which is `None`, because you don't `return` anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You indeed can use the `group` method to extract the match

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match(r"[^@]+@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+){1,2}", 'xx@gmail.com')
>>> m
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='xx@gmail.com'>
>>> m.group(0)
'xx@gmail.com'
```

If you are running into that error, it means whatever string you passed into your function did not have a match, and thus `m` was `None` and there is nothing to display.

```
>>> m = re.match(r"[^@]+@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+){1,2}", 'bad_input')
>>> m
>>> type(m)
<class 'NoneType'>
```